# When I try to use a gameObject, thats outside the "OnCollisionEnter" function it does not work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, gun

When I try to use a gameObject, thats outside the "OnCollisionEnter" function it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) 
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Finish")
    {
        //temporary object (created outside the function)
        tempGO = other.gameObject;
        Instantiate(particles, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

        if(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Gun>().fn90)
        {
            tempGO.GetComponent<Health>().Dmg(3);
        }
        else if(!GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Gun>().fn90)
        {
            tempGO.GetComponent<Health>().Dmg(10);
        }

        tempGO = null;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

There is an error on 20th line (first if, the script couldnt find the "other.gameObject")

Comment: An unusual way yo get the camera object.   Normally Camera.main.gameObject would work

Comment: can you open the console(CTRL + Shift + C).., it may be easier o pinpoint where the null ref coming from

Comment: are you sure particles is assigned?

Comment: btw your `else if(!GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Gun>().fn90)` could simply be `else`. You could even simplify it further using a ternary `tempGO.GetComponent<Health>().Dmg(Camera.main.GetComponent<Gun>().fn90 ? 3 : 10);`